# MySql enter duplicate rows into table

Tags: mysql, duplicates, sql-insert

I would like to enter two of the same emails as two different rows into MySQL table Person. However, it keeps only one row. How do I modify my code? Thanks.

```
create table if not exists Person (
    Id int auto_increment primary key,
    Email varchar(20)
);

insert into Person(Email)
    values ('abc@efg.com'),
    ('abc@efg.com')
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks ok

**[SQL fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/511661/1)**

**OUTPUT**

```
| Id |       Email |
|----|-------------|
|  1 | abc@efg.com |
|  2 | abc@efg.com |
```